# namei command in MacOs

Tags: macos, bash, unix, operating-system

It may be trivial question, but I'm looking over the internet and SO about **namei** in **macos**. I can't find it on Yosemite, also homebrew doesn't contains such package to install. From what I was searching, MacPorts doesn't have it neither. Could some pro developers from MacOs help me or suggest other command that will be able to check for ownership and permissions on a path?

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as an answer vs. a comment although I will make a comment first and that is, this doesn't appear to be a question suited to this forum and you might want to ask elsewhere, e.g. [Super User](http://superuser.com).

That said, `namei` is a part of the `util-linux` [package](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) and as such is not a command normally found under OS X.  If it's even possible, you have to download the source code for `util-linux` and then selectively compile `namei` and then manually install `namei` by itself as you would not want to compile and install the entire `util-linux` package under OS X.  I've done similar under OS X with individual utilities of the [GNU Core Utilities](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) package however not with the `util-linux` package.